# How can I include server variables in JS with CSP?

Tags: content-security-policy, helmet.js

In my app I have some server variables:

```
{{# serverVars }}
    <script>
        window.serverVars = {{{ . }}};
    </script>
{{/ serverVars }}
```

This is used to set, eg, `window.serverVars.countryCode` to the countryCode as determined by the server using geoIP.

Now in CSP this is considered `unsafe-inline` which is generally bad. So what's the best approach:

- Using a nonce is difficult: the nonce is unique per request and most CSP libraries (eg, Helmet) considered CSP policies static
- Using a hash is difficult: the value of serverVars is unique per request and most CSP libraries (eg, [Helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs)) considered CSP policies static
- `unsafe-inline` for `script-src` is considered insecure

**What's the best way to add dynamic server variables into client side JavaScript with CSP?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve seen some people use `script`s with `type`s that the browser won’t execute, then fetch and parse those from the trusted JavaScript. For example, in the HTML:

```html
<script id="config" type="application/x-configuration">
    {"environment": "production", ...}
</script>
```

And then in your JavaScript file:

```js
var config = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('config').textContent);
```

You could also put it as a `data` attribute if you’d prefer, e.g.:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-config="{&quot;environment&quot;: &quot;production&quot;, ...}">
    ...
```

And again fetching it in your JavaScript:

```js
var config = JSON.parse(document.documentElement.dataset.config);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still be considered an inline-script, even if it's `type="application/x-configuration"`?

Comment: @mikemaccana: I admit I’m not very familiar with CSP, but I don’t see why it would be a problem. What’s the worst CSP would do, block execution? It’s not like it was going to be executed in the first place. And if it doesn’t work, there’s also the second solution with the `data-*` attribute.

Comment: Indeed. Testing it solution 1 works fine - it seems non-executable types aren't considered `unsafe-inline `

Comment: Just make sure the data in those json blocks is properly escaped! Here's a good blog post on this technique: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/json-dom-csp

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @icktoofay's excellent answer, I want to point out that some CSP libraries, eg Yahoo's [Express CSP](https://github.com/yahoo/express-csp) have a `useScriptNonce` that will dynamically generate nonce's for `scripts`.